# Does RSA encryption always pad small amounts of data to some larger size?

Tags: encryption, rsa

If I encrypt 160 bits (20 bytes) of data using an RSA 1024 **private** key, will the result always be 128 bytes? This seems to be the case in my experiements, but I want to be sure.

For example,

```
/bin/echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 -sign privateKey.der -keyform DER > enc.txt
```

always seems to result in a 128 byte file `enc.txt` even after I generate new public/private keys (the private key saved into the file `privateKey.der`).

Comment: If OpenSSL uses [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) then yes. I'm not sure however which padding scheme it uses so I can't comment on that. Maybe others can clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically yes. That's how RSA works, as described in [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447).

On **encryption**, the input data is first "padded", i.e. expanded with some randomness and structure, and then turned into a big integer value *m* in the *0..n-1* range (*n* being the modulus). That value is then raised to the power *e* (the public exponent) modulo *n*, yielding another integer in the *0..n-1* range. The result is encoded into bytes with what the RFC calls [I2OSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-4.1) (big-endian unsigned convention). For a 1024-bit RSA modulus, you will always get a 128-byte result.

Similarly, a RSA **signature**, for a 1024-bit key, always has length exactly 128 bytes.

---

**Mandatory reminder:** no, you are not "encrypting with the private key". The whole notion of "encrypting with the private key" is a flawed analogy, which works only for RSA, and actually does not work for RSA, precisely because it completely fails at taking padding into account. You are *signing*. And, indeed, you use the `-sign` command-line flag. RSA is *two* algorithms, which happen to share some common mathematical structure, but not all of it; things will be clearer if you keep thinking about RSA *encryption* and RSA *signatures* as distinct process.